# How do I use arrays in combination with constructors?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I'm currently making a depression-simulation program where I created Human objects that have multiple parameters which alter the way the depression will affect them.

My issue is that I am able to create singular human objects, such as
`Human steve = new Human("Steve", 25, 'm', 97000, 1, 3, false, false, 1, Human.happiness);`
but I do not know how to create Human arrays that include the parameters that a single Human has. For example, I can create a Human array `Human[] test = new Human[3];` with 3 Humans in it, but I do not know how to provide those Humans with the parameters.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Human {
    private String name; // your name
    private int age; // how old you are
    private int wealth; // your average yearly income
    private int amtFriendsFamily; // how many friends/family members you are
                                    // close to
    private int levelOfEducation; /*
                                     * 1 = no education, 2 = high school
                                     * education, 3 = college education, 4 =
                                     * upper level college education
                                     */
    private boolean married;
    private boolean seeksDoctor; // true = seeks a doctor, false = does not seek
                                    // a doctor
    private char sex; // m = male, f = female
    private int race; // 1 = white, 2 = black, 3 = hispanic, 4 = asian, 5 =
                        // mideast
    static int happiness = 75;

    private String sSex, sMarried, sDoct, sRace, sEdu;
    private String[] names = { "Sally", "Karl", "Steven", "Emily" };

    public Human(String name1, int age1, char sex1, int wealth1, int amtFriendsFamily1, int levelOfEducation1,
            boolean married1, boolean seeksDoctor1, int race1, int happiness1) {
        name = name1;
        age = age1;
        wealth = wealth1;
        amtFriendsFamily = amtFriendsFamily1;
        levelOfEducation = levelOfEducation1;
        married = married1;
        seeksDoctor = seeksDoctor1;
        sex = sex1;
        race = race1;
        happiness = happiness1;

        if (sex == 'm')
            sSex = "male";
        else if (sex == 'f')
            sSex = "female";
        else
            sSex = "foreign gender";

        if (married == false)
            sMarried = "is not married, ";
        else
            sMarried = "is married, ";

        if (seeksDoctor == false)
            sDoct = "does not seek doctors.";
        else
            sDoct = "seeks doctors.";

        if (race == 1)
            sRace = "White";
        else if (race == 2)
            sRace = "Black";
        else if (race == 3)
            sRace = "Hispanic";
        else if (race == 4)
            sRace = "Asian";
        else if (race == 5)
            sRace = "Middle Eastern";

        if (levelOfEducation == 1)
            sEdu = " has no formal education, ";
        else if (levelOfEducation == 2)
            sEdu = " has a high school education, ";
        else if (levelOfEducation == 3)
            sEdu = " has a college education, ";
        else if (levelOfEducation == 4)
            sEdu = " has an upper-college level or higher education, ";

        System.out.println(name + " is a " + age + " year old " + sRace + " " + sSex + " who makes $" + wealth
                + " per year," + " has " + amtFriendsFamily + " friends and family members combined," + sEdu + sMarried
                + "and " + sDoct);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is along these lines:

```
Human[] test = new Human[3];
Human temp = new Human("Steve", 25, 'm', 97000, 1, 3, false, false, 1, Human.happiness);
test[0] = temp;
```

Just redefine `temp` for each object in the array and then set one of the objects in the array equal to `temp`. Of course, it would be preferable to do this in a loop, but in this case that would only be possible if the program grabs user/file input for each `Human` object.

Comment: I feel so stupid for not thinking of that.  What I would do is 


    `Human[] test = new Human[3];`

    `Human temp = new Human("Steve", 25, 'm', 97000, 1, 3, false, false,  1, Human.happiness);`

    `test[0] = temp;`
but instead of setting values, randomize it to create a new, unique Human every time, correct?

Comment: We've all been there. Sometimes it just takes a fresh perspective ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
// doesn't need size in initialization, the compiler can count the number of new Human instances 
Human[] test = new Human[] {
    new Human(...), new Human(...), new Human(...)
}
```

Or use indexes

```
Human[] test = new Human[3];
test[0] = new Human(...);
```